Is my implementation of the Leiden algorithm in Java incorrect?
I have implemented the Louvain and Leiden algorithms without graph aggregation. My Leiden implementation, with the resolution parameter gamma set to 0.5, does not seem to be working correctly. My program first places two nodes in a community and later removes one node from the same community, with the change in the value of the CPM function being positive both times. This doesn't seem to be how the Leiden algorithm should work.
The graphs are present in the data subfolder of my project folder as text files with integers representing nodes and rows representing edges. The one I'm working with right now is present in a file named "example_graph_changed.txt". It is shown below:
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
3 6
4 8
6 5
6 7
6 8
8 5
8 7
8 9
7 9
7 10
9 10
9 13
10 11
10 13
10 14
10 15
13 11
13 12
11 12
11 14
11 15
11 16
14 16

I have a class to load the graphs (named GraphLoader) and a Graph interface. GraphLoader is present in the util package of my project folder, while the Graph interface is present in the graph package along with all the other classes I have created.
GraphLoader:
package util;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class GraphLoader {
    /**
     * Loads graph with data from a file.
     * The file should consist of lines with 2 integers each, corresponding
     * to a "from" vertex and a "to" vertex.
     */ 
    public static void loadGraph(graph.Graph g, String filename) {
        Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        // Iterate over the lines in the file, adding new
        // vertices as they are found and connecting them with edges.
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int v1 = sc.nextInt();
            int v2 = sc.nextInt();
            if (!seen.contains(v1)) {
                g.addVertex(v1);
                seen.add(v1);
            }
            if (!seen.contains(v2)) {
                g.addVertex(v2);
                seen.add(v2);
            }
            g.addEdge(v1, v2);
        }
        
        sc.close();
    }
}

Graph:
package graph;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public interface Graph {
    /* Creates a vertex with the given number. */
    public void addVertex(int num);
    
    /* Creates an edge from the first vertex to the second. */
    public void addEdge(int i1, int i2);

    /* Finds the egonet centered at a given node. */
    public Graph getEgonet(int center);

    /* Returns all SCCs in a directed graph */
    public List<Graph> getSCCs();
    
    /* Return the graph's connections in a readable format. 
     * The keys in this HashMap are the vertices in the graph.
     * The values are the nodes that are reachable via a directed
     * edge from the corresponding key. 
     * The returned representation ignores edge weights and 
     * multi-edges.  */
    public HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> exportGraph();
}

The class implementing the Graph interface that I use to actually store the graph as an object is shown below:
package graph;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class ComDetGraph implements Graph {
    
    //data structures to store nodes and edges
    private HashMap<Integer, ComDetNode> nodeMap;
    private HashSet<ComDetEdge> edges;
    
    public ComDetGraph () {
        this.nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.edges = new HashSet<>();
    }
    
    //methods to expose properties of the graph
    public int getNumVertices() {
        return nodeMap.values().size();
    }
    
    public int getNumEdges() {
        return edges.size();
    }
    
    public HashMap<Integer, ComDetNode> getNodeMap() {
        return nodeMap;
    }
    
    public HashSet<ComDetEdge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    //methods to add vertices and edges
    @Override
    public void addVertex(int num) {
        ComDetNode n = nodeMap.get(num);
        if (n == null) {
            n = new ComDetNode(num);
            nodeMap.put(num, n);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addEdge(int i1, int i2) {
        ComDetNode n1 = nodeMap.get(i1);
        ComDetNode n2 = nodeMap.get(i2);
        
        if (n1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node with value " + i1 + 
                    " does not exist in graph");
        } 
        if (n2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node with value " + i2 + 
                    " does not exist in graph");
        }
        
        ComDetEdge edge = new ComDetEdge(n1, n2, 1);
        edges.add(edge);
        n1.addNeighbor(n2);
        n2.addNeighbor(n1);
    }

    @Override
    public Graph getEgonet(int center) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Graph> getSCCs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> exportGraph() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

I have created the classes ComDetNode and ComDetEdge for storing nodes and edges as objects.
ComDetNode:
package graph;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ComDetNode {
    
    /*the node object has an integer value and a set of nodes as its
    neighbors*/
    private Integer value;
    private HashSet<ComDetNode> neighbors;
    
    //constructor
    public ComDetNode(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.neighbors = new HashSet<>();
    }

    //getters and setters
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public HashSet<ComDetNode> getNeighbors() {
        return neighbors;
    }
    
    public void addNeighbor (ComDetNode nbr) {
        neighbors.add(nbr);
    }

    /*since many methods will be removing and adding these nodes to 
     * sets and maps, these methods are overridden to ensure removal
     * and addition can be carried out without the object hashCodes needing
     * to match exactly*/
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ComDetNode other = (ComDetNode) obj;
        return Objects.equals(value, other.value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + value + "";
    }

}

ComDetEdge:
package graph;

public class ComDetEdge {
    
    //starting and ending nodes of the edge
    private ComDetNode start;
    private ComDetNode end;
    
    public ComDetEdge (ComDetNode start, ComDetNode end, int weight) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    
    //getter for the end node
    public ComDetNode getEndNode() {
        return end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return start + "->" + end;
    }

}

I also have a class to store partitions of the graph, as defined in the context of the Louvain and Leiden algorithms:
package graph;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Partition {
    
    /*data structures to ensure quick retrieval of community ID for a given node
     * and quick retrieval of set of nodes in a community for a given community
     * ID*/
    private HashMap<ComDetNode, Integer> nodeIDMap;
    private HashMap<Integer, HashSet<ComDetNode>> iDNodeSetMap;
    
    public Partition() {
        nodeIDMap = new HashMap<>();
        iDNodeSetMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    //getters
    public HashMap<ComDetNode, Integer> getNodeIDMap() {
        return nodeIDMap;
    }
    
    public HashMap<Integer, HashSet<ComDetNode>> getIDNodeSetMap() {
        return iDNodeSetMap;
    }
    
    //getters for community ID and node set
    public int getComID (ComDetNode node) {
        return nodeIDMap.get(node);
    }
    
    public HashSet<ComDetNode> getNodeSet (int id) {
        return iDNodeSetMap.get(id);
    }

}

Finally, I have a class where I've written the functions to use in the Louvain and Leiden algorithms, and a main function to run them.
package graph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import util.GraphLoader;

public class ComDet {
    
    /*method to create a singleton partition of the graph i.e. store every
     * node in its own separate community*/
    public Partition singletonPartition (ComDetGraph g) {
        Partition partition = new Partition();
        for (ComDetNode node : g.getNodeMap().values()) {
            /*placing nodes and community IDs in one of the maps in the 
             * Partition object*/
            partition.getNodeIDMap().put(node, node.getValue());
            
            //a node set to store just the current node
            HashSet<ComDetNode> newNodeSet = new HashSet<>();
            newNodeSet.add(node);
            
            //storing the community IDs along with corresponding node sets
            partition.getIDNodeSetMap().put(node.getValue(), newNodeSet);
        }
        return partition;
    }
    
    //method to create a singleton partition of a community
    /*exactly the same as above except only for a community and not an entire 
    graph*/
    private Partition singletonPartitionForComm (HashSet<ComDetNode> comm) {
        Partition partition = new Partition();
        for (ComDetNode node : comm) {
            partition.getNodeIDMap().put(node, node.getValue());
            HashSet<ComDetNode> newNodeSet = new HashSet<>();
            newNodeSet.add(node);
            partition.getIDNodeSetMap().put(node.getValue(), newNodeSet);
        }
        return partition;
    }
    
    //function to calculate modularity for the community C
    public double q (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, int C, double gamma) {
        
        int numEdges = g.getNumEdges();
        double q_C = 0;
        double int_comp = 0;
        double out_comp = 0;
        
        /*calculating the internal edges of the community and the total number
        of edges for each node in the community*/
        for (ComDetNode n : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C)) {
            for (ComDetNode nbr : n.getNeighbors()) {
                if (partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                    ++int_comp;
                }
                ++out_comp;
            }
        }
        
        //normalization and other arithmetic operations
        double nEC = (double) (2 * numEdges);
        int_comp /= nEC;
        out_comp *= out_comp;
        out_comp /= (Math.pow((2 * numEdges), 2));
        out_comp *= gamma;
        q_C = int_comp - out_comp;
        
        return q_C;
        
    }
    
    //Calculating Constant Potts Model (CPM) function value for community C
    //Similar to above
    public double cpm (Partition partition, int C, double gamma) {
        
        double cpm = 0;
        double int_comp = 0;
        double out_comp = 0;
        
        //expected number of edges in C using CPM
        int n_c = partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).size();
        double n_c_2 = (double) n_c * ((n_c - 1) / 2);
        
        out_comp *= (gamma * n_c_2);
        
        //actual number of edges in C
        for (ComDetNode n : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C)) {
            for (ComDetNode nbr : n.getNeighbors()) {
                if (partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                    ++int_comp;
                }
            }
        }
        
        cpm = int_comp - out_comp;
        
        return cpm;
    }
    
    /*Calculating change in modularity on moving node i from community C to 
     * community D*/
    public double del_Q 
    (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, ComDetNode i, int C, int D, double gamma) {
        
        int numEdges = g.getNumEdges();
        double step1output = 0.0;
        double step2output = 0.0;
        int deg_i_orig = i.getNeighbors().size();
        int deg_i_C = deg_i_orig;
        int deg_i_D = deg_i_orig;
        int sum_deg_C = 0;
        int sum_deg_D = 0;
        double del_Q = 0;
        
        //calculating degrees of node i in communities C and D
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_C;
            } 
        }
        
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(D).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_D;
            } 
        }
        
        //calculating sums of degrees of nodes in communities C and D
        for (ComDetNode n : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C)) {
            sum_deg_C += n.getNeighbors().size();
        }
        
        for (ComDetNode n : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(D)) {
            sum_deg_D += n.getNeighbors().size();
        }
        
        /*if node i is being moved from community C to D, its contribution to
         * the sum of degrees of nodes in D must be considered*/
        if (C != D) {
            sum_deg_D += i.getNeighbors().size();
        }
        
        //normalization and other arithmetic
        step1output = (((double) -1 / numEdges) * (deg_i_C)) + 
                      ((deg_i_orig / (2 * Math.pow(numEdges, 2))) 
                      * sum_deg_C * gamma);
        
        step2output = (((double) 1 / numEdges) * (deg_i_D)) - 
                  ((deg_i_orig / (2 * Math.pow(numEdges, 2))) 
                  * sum_deg_D * gamma);
        
        del_Q = step1output + step2output;
        
        return del_Q;
    }
    
    //Calculating change in CPM on moving node i from community C to community D
    public double del_CPM 
    (Partition partition, ComDetNode i, int C, int D, double gamma) {
        
        double delta_C = 0.0;
        double delta_D = 0.0;
        int deg_i_orig = i.getNeighbors().size();
        int deg_i_C = deg_i_orig;
        int deg_i_D = deg_i_orig;
        int n_c = partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).size();
        int n_d = partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(D).size();
        double del_CPM = 0;
        
        //degrees of node i in C and D
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_C;
            } 
        }
        
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(D).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_D;
            } 
        }
        
        //changes in CPM for moving i out of C and into D
        delta_C = (double) -deg_i_C + (gamma * (n_c - 1));
        delta_D = (double) deg_i_D - (gamma * n_d);
        
        del_CPM = delta_C + delta_D;
        
        return del_CPM;
    }
    
    /*Calculating change in modularity on moving node i from community C to
    the empty community*/
    public double del_Q_empty 
    (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, ComDetNode i, int C, double gamma) {
        
        int numEdges = g.getNumEdges();
        int deg_i_orig = i.getNeighbors().size();
        int deg_i_C = deg_i_orig;
        int sum_deg_C = 0;
        double del_Q = 0;
        
        //degree of i in C and sum of degrees of C
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_C;
            } 
        }
        
        for (ComDetNode n : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C)) {
            sum_deg_C += n.getNeighbors().size();
        }
        
        //change in modularity for moving i out of C
        double del_Q_1 = (((double) -1 / numEdges) * (deg_i_C)) + 
                 ((deg_i_orig / (2 * Math.pow(numEdges, 2))) *
                        sum_deg_C * gamma);
        
        //change in modularity for moving i into the empty community
        double del_Q_2_1 = ((double) -gamma / 2);
        double del_Q_2_2 = ((double) deg_i_orig / numEdges);
        double del_Q_2 = del_Q_2_1 * Math.pow(del_Q_2_2, 2);
        del_Q = del_Q_1 + del_Q_2;
        
        return del_Q;
    }
    
    /*Calculating change in CPM on moving the node i from the community C to
     * the empty community*/
    public double del_CPM_empty 
    (Partition partition, ComDetNode i, int C, double gamma) {
        
        int deg_i_orig = i.getNeighbors().size();
        int deg_i_C = deg_i_orig;
        int n_c = partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).size();
        double del_CPM = 0;
        
        //degree of i in C
        for (ComDetNode nbr : i.getNeighbors()) {
            if (!partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).contains(nbr)) {
                --deg_i_C;
            } 
        }
        
        //change in CPM
        del_CPM = (double) deg_i_C - (gamma * n_c);
        del_CPM += gamma;
        
        return del_CPM;
    }
    
    //Modularity for a certain partition of the graph
    public double hLvn (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        double h = 0.0;
        
        //sum of modularities for each community
        for (int C : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().keySet()) {
            h += q(g, partition, C, gamma);
        }
        
        return h;
    }
    
    //CPM for a certain partition of the graph
    public double hLdn (Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        double h = 0.0;
        
        //sum of CPM values for each community
        for (int C : partition.getIDNodeSetMap().keySet()) {
            h += cpm(partition, C, gamma);
        }
        
        return h;
    }
    
    //local move for the Louvain algorithm
    public Partition moveNodes 
    (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        double h_old = 0.0;
        
        do {
            
            //calculating modularity of old partition
            h_old = hLvn(g, partition, gamma);
            
            //randomizing order of nodes
            List<ComDetNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>(g.getNodeMap().values());
            Collections.shuffle(nodes);
            
            for (ComDetNode node : nodes) {
                
                //max value of change in modularity
                double max_del_H = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                int nC = partition.getNodeIDMap().get(node);
                
                /*map to store the change in modularity for each community
                 we might move this node to*/
                HashMap<Integer, Double> comm_to_del_H = new HashMap<>();
                
                //moving this node into each of its neighbor's communities
                for (ComDetNode nbr : node.getNeighbors()) {
                    int C = partition.getNodeIDMap().get(nbr);
                    
                    /*ensuring communities with the same change in modularity as 
                     a community already contained in the map aren't added*/
                    if (!comm_to_del_H.containsKey(C)) {
                        
                        /*computing change in modularity for this community,
                         * storing it and updating the max value
                         */
                        double del_H = del_Q(g, partition, node, nC, C, gamma);
                        comm_to_del_H.put(C, del_H);
                        max_del_H = Math.max(del_H, max_del_H);
                    }
                }
                
                /*computing change in modularity for moving this node into 
                 * the empty community, storing it and updating max*/
                double del_H_empty = del_Q_empty(g, partition, node, nC, gamma);
                comm_to_del_H.put(Integer.MIN_VALUE, del_H_empty);
                max_del_H = Math.max(del_H_empty, max_del_H);
                
                int newCom = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                
                /*only if the change in modularity is positive will we perform
                 * a local move*/
                if (max_del_H > 0) {
                    
                    //find community corresponding to max change in modularity
                    for (int C : comm_to_del_H.keySet()) {
                        if (comm_to_del_H.get(C) == max_del_H) {
                            newCom = C;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    //if empty community, set its ID to a new value
                    if (newCom == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                        newCom = g.getNumVertices();
                        ++newCom;
                    }
                    
                    /*remove node from its old community and add it to its new
                    one*/
                    partition.getNodeIDMap().put(node, newCom);
                    partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(nC).remove(node);
                    if (partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(nC).isEmpty()) {
                        partition.getIDNodeSetMap().remove(nC);
                    }
                    if (newCom == (g.getNumVertices() + 1)) {
                        HashSet<ComDetNode> emptyPlOne = 
                                new HashSet<>();
                        emptyPlOne.add(node);
                        partition.getIDNodeSetMap().
                        put(newCom, emptyPlOne);
                    } else {
                        partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(newCom).add(node);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } while (hLvn(g, partition, gamma) > h_old);
        
        return partition;
        
    }
    
    //local move for the Leiden algorithm
    public Partition moveNodesFast (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        /*randomizing order of nodes, creating queue and set for dealing with
        the smart local move procedure*/
        List<ComDetNode> nodes = 
                new ArrayList<>(g.getNodeMap().values());
        Collections.shuffle(nodes, new Random(123));
        LinkedList<ComDetNode> nodeLinked = new LinkedList<>(nodes);
        HashSet<ComDetNode> nodesNew = new HashSet<>(nodes);
        
        do {
            ComDetNode node = nodeLinked.remove();
            nodesNew.remove(node);
            
            //max value of change in CPM
            double max_del_CPM = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            int nC = partition.getNodeIDMap().get(node);
            
            //map to store communities and change in CPM
            HashMap<Integer, Double> comm_to_del_CPM = new HashMap<>();
            
            /*iterating over neighbors to store changes in CPM and find max 
            change in CPM*/
            for (ComDetNode nbr : node.getNeighbors()) {
                int C = partition.getNodeIDMap().get(nbr);
                if (!comm_to_del_CPM.containsKey(C)) {
                    double del_CPM = del_CPM(partition, node, nC, C, gamma);
                    comm_to_del_CPM.put(C, del_CPM);
                    max_del_CPM = Math.max(max_del_CPM, del_CPM);
                }
            }
            
            //doing the same as above for empty community
            double del_CPM_empty = del_CPM_empty(partition, node, nC, gamma);
            comm_to_del_CPM.put(Integer.MIN_VALUE, del_CPM_empty);
            max_del_CPM = Math.max(max_del_CPM, del_CPM_empty);
            
            int newCom = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            
            //moving only if change in CPM > 0
            if (max_del_CPM > 0) {
                
                //finding appropriate community with max change in CPM
                for (int C : comm_to_del_CPM.keySet()) {
                    if (comm_to_del_CPM.get(C) == max_del_CPM) {
                        newCom = C;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (newCom == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                    newCom = g.getNumVertices();
                    ++newCom;
                }
                
                //removing node from old community and moving it to the new one
                partition.getNodeIDMap().put(node, newCom);
                partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(nC).remove(node);
                if (partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(nC).isEmpty()) {
                    partition.getIDNodeSetMap().remove(nC);
                }
                if (newCom == (g.getNumVertices() + 1)) {
                    HashSet<ComDetNode> emptyPlOne = 
                            new HashSet<>();
                    emptyPlOne.add(node);
                    partition.getIDNodeSetMap().
                    put(newCom, emptyPlOne);
                } else {
                    partition.getIDNodeSetMap().get(newCom).add(node);
                }
                
                /*adding neighbors not in the new community to the queue and set
                to visit later*/
                for (ComDetNode nbr : node.getNeighbors()) {
                    int nbrCom = partition.getNodeIDMap().get(nbr);
                    if (nbrCom != newCom) {
                        nodeLinked.add(node);
                        nodesNew.add(node);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        } while (!nodeLinked.isEmpty());
        
        return partition;
    }
    
    //Leiden algorithm partition refinement
    public Partition refinePartition 
    (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        Partition p_refined = singletonPartition(g);
        
        //merging those subsets of the community that cause an optimum change in 
        //CPM
        for (HashSet<ComDetNode> comm : 
            partition.getIDNodeSetMap().values()) {
            Partition p_comm = singletonPartitionForComm(comm);
            p_refined = mergeNodeSubsets(g, p_comm, comm, gamma);
        }
        
        return p_refined;
    }
    
    public Partition mergeNodeSubsets
    (ComDetGraph g, Partition p, HashSet<ComDetNode> comm, double gamma) {
        
        HashSet<ComDetNode> R = new HashSet<>();
        
        for (ComDetNode n : comm) {
            HashSet<ComDetNode> nSingle = new HashSet<>();
            nSingle.add(n);
            
            //if well-connected then add to the set for further processing
            if (checkGammaConnected(nSingle, comm, gamma)) {
                R.add(n);
            }
        }
        
        //randomize order
        ArrayList<ComDetNode> R_rnd = new ArrayList<>(R);
        Collections.shuffle(R_rnd, new Random(123));
        
        for (ComDetNode node : R_rnd) {
            int C = p.getNodeIDMap().get(node);
            
            //if singleton then process further
            if (p.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).size() == 1) {
                HashMap<Integer, HashSet<ComDetNode>> T = new HashMap<>();
                
                //find well-connected communities
                for (Integer Co : p.getIDNodeSetMap().keySet()) {
                    HashSet<ComDetNode> com = p.getIDNodeSetMap().get(Co);
                    if (checkGammaConnected(com, comm, gamma)) {
                        T.put(Co, com);
                    }
                }
                
                HashMap<Integer, Double> comm_to_prob = new HashMap<>();
                
                //find probability of move causing an optimum change in CPM
                for (Integer Co : T.keySet()) {
                    if (del_CPM(p, node, C, Co, gamma) >= 0) {
                        double exponent = 10 * del_CPM(p, node, C, Co, gamma);
                        double prob = Math.exp(exponent);
                        comm_to_prob.put(Co, prob);
                    } else {
                        comm_to_prob.put(Co, 0.0);
                    }
                }
                
                //randomly select community to move to with probabilities 
                //proportional to change in CPM
                int com = randomWeightedSelection(comm_to_prob);
                
                p.getNodeIDMap().put(node, com);
                p.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).remove(node);
                if (p.getIDNodeSetMap().get(C).isEmpty()) {
                    p.getIDNodeSetMap().remove(C);
                }
                p.getIDNodeSetMap().get(com).add(node);
            }
        }
        
        return p;
    }
    
    //randomly select community with probability proportional to the change in
    //modularity
    private int randomWeightedSelection(HashMap<Integer, Double> comm_to_prob) {
        
        double totalWt = 0;
        
        //find total weight for the set of communities
        for (Integer Co : comm_to_prob.keySet()) {
            totalWt += comm_to_prob.get(Co);
        }
        
        //randomly calculate a weight
        double rnd = Math.random() * totalWt;
        
        double commWeight = 0;
        
        //return community with weight above randomly calculated weight
        for (Integer Co : comm_to_prob.keySet()) {
            commWeight += comm_to_prob.get(Co);
            if (commWeight >= rnd) {
                return Co;
            }
        }
        
        return 0;
    }

    //check if a subset of a set of nodes is well-connected to the rest of the
    //set
    private boolean checkGammaConnected 
    (HashSet<ComDetNode> T, HashSet<ComDetNode> S, double gamma) {
        
        double S_not_T_edges = 0.0;
        
        for (ComDetNode node : T) {
            for (ComDetNode nbr : node.getNeighbors()) {
                if (S.contains(nbr) && !T.contains(nbr)) {
                    S_not_T_edges++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        double secondTerm = gamma * T.size() * (S.size() - T.size());
        
        return S_not_T_edges >= secondTerm;
    }

    //calculate optimum partition using the Louvain algorithm
    public Partition louvain (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        
        double q_prev = hLvn(g, partition, gamma);
        Partition p_new = moveNodes(g, partition, gamma);
        if ((hLvn(g, p_new, gamma) - q_prev) >= 0.001) {
            louvain(g, p_new, gamma);
        }
        
        return p_new;
        
    }
    
    //calculate optimum partition using the Leiden algorithm
    public Partition leiden (ComDetGraph g, Partition partition, double gamma) {
        double cpm_prev = hLdn(partition, gamma);
        Partition p_new = moveNodesFast(g, partition, gamma);
        
        if ((hLdn(p_new, gamma) - cpm_prev) >= 0.001) {
            leiden(g, p_new, gamma);
        }
        
        return p_new;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //load graph and calculate final partition using Leiden algorithm
        ComDet cd = new ComDet();
        ComDetGraph g = new ComDetGraph();
        GraphLoader.loadGraph(g, "data/example_graph_changed.txt");
        Partition sP = cd.singletonPartition(g);
        Partition finalPart = cd.leiden(g, sP, 0.5);
        System.out.println(finalPart.getIDNodeSetMap());
        
    }

}

The node numbered 10 is moved into a community with the node numbered 15, and in a later iteration of the outer loop of the moveNodesFast() function is moved out of the same community. I don't understand why this is happening. I have clearly made a mistake somewhere, but since the CPM formula is correct as far as I understand, I have no idea why the program is computing an increase for a local move and an increase for the reverse of that same local move.

You should try debugging the program and if you can not find the issue try to narrow the question. Seems too much code for an [so] question.
